# How to count consecutive days in a list of dates

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary, count

```
# below is the example of list of dates:
date_list = [date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 5)]
```

I was thinking of counting all consecutive dates and make a dictionary where the key value is the start date and the value is the count of consecutive days.

```
dic = {date(2021, 1, 2): 2, date(2021, 1, 5): 1}
```

Could anyone help me what steps I should take to accomplish the above task? Should I approach the problem in a different way? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like an algorithm problem, here I list the codes with some test cases

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta


def is_consecutive(date1, date2):
    return True if date1 + timedelta(days=1) == date2 else False


def my_func(date_list):
    if not date_list:
        return {}
    if len(date_list) == 1:
        return {date_list[0]: 1}

    date_list.sort()
    res = {}
    start_date = date_list[0]
    cnt = 1
    for idx, cur_date in enumerate(date_list[1:], start=1):
        # print(idx, cur_date)
        if is_consecutive(date_list[idx - 1], cur_date):
            cnt += 1
        else:
            res[start_date] = cnt
            start_date = cur_date
            cnt = 1
    else:
        res[start_date] = cnt
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # below is the example of list of dates:
    date_list = [date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 5)]
    # {datetime.date(2021, 1, 2): 2, datetime.date(2021, 1, 5): 1}
    print(my_func(date_list))

    date_list = [date(2021, 1, 5), date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 6), date(2021, 1, 31),
                 date(2021, 2, 1), date(2021, 2, 2)]
    # {datetime.date(2021, 1, 2): 2, datetime.date(2021, 1, 5): 2, datetime.date(2021, 1, 31): 3}
    print(my_func(date_list))

    date_list = [date(2021, 1, 5)]
    # {datetime.date(2021, 1, 5): 1}
    print(my_func(date_list))

    date_list = []
    # {}
    print(my_func(date_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve your problem. In this case a simple and effective approach is to just have a `for` loop where you check if the condition (the dates are consecutives) applies to the current loop item and the "ongoing" group of dates:

```
from datetime import date

date_list = [date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 5)]

result = {}

c = date_list[0]
n = 1

for d in date_list[1:]:
    if (d - c).days == n:
        n = n + 1
    else:
        result[c] = n
        c = d
        n = 1

result[c] = n

print(result)
```

We start with a "group" in which we place the first date and a counter `n` for the number of elements in the group. Then we start the loop (from the second item). At each iteration we check the condition: is the current date `n` days in the future from the first date in the group? If yes we increment `n` and go on, else we store the data in the dictionary. Note that I am talking about a "group" of dates but you don't need to store all of them: the first one and `n` (the number of days spanned by the group) is sufficient here.

Important: when using this approach you always need to account for the fact the last group of items need to be processed outside the loop.

As I said there are other approaches: I choose this one because, IMHO, it is quite easy to understand how it works.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @ext_vayne happy to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `date_list` and compare each date to the previous one to see if they are consecutive days. Assuming you are using the built-in datetime.date class you can use the [toordinal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) method to make comparing dates easy. You can also use a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) of 1 day. You will want to keep track of the first date in a chain on consecutive dates so you can continue to access it in the dictionary.

The following code should work assuming your date list is sorted.

```
from datetime import date
date_list = [date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 5)]
dic = {}

date_range_start = None
for i in range(len(date_list)):
    if i == 0:
        date_range_start = date_list[i]
        dic[date_range_start] = 1
    else:
        if date_list[i].toordinal() - date_list[i-1].toordinal() == 1:
            dic[date_range_start] += 1
        else:
            date_range_start = date_list[i]
            dic[date_range_start] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:
First sort the list by doing `date_list.sort()`, this is rather important since you will not end up with the correct result if it is not sorted.

Then just use a for loop to iterate the entire list, keep track of the previous day by setting up a variable `current_date`, compare the current day with the previous day and current day, if it is consecutive then increment the counter such as `current_max_consecutive_day` else reset the previous date with the new date and the counter.

```py
from datetime import date

date_list = [date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 5)]
date_list.sort() # if the list is not sorted, then please sort it

dic = {}
current_max_consecutive_day = 1
current_date = date_list[0]

# This only work if the list is sorted
for d in date_list:
    if d.day-current_date.day == 1:
        # if we found a consecutive day then add it to the dictionary
        current_max_consecutive_day += 1
    else:
        # otherwise create a new item in the dic and restart the count
        current_max_consecutive_day = 1
        current_date = d
    dic[current_date] = current_max_consecutive_day
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers))

Comment: @Ahx thanks for the tip! I rushed to provide an answer, I will try to be more elaborate for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list into a dictionary with a count of one for each date.  Then merge the dates that are consecutive using each day as a starting point:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

date_list = [date(2021, 1, 3), date(2021, 1, 2), date(2021, 1, 5)]

dic = dict.fromkeys(date_list,1) # start with each date = span of 1
for d in date_list:              # try to merge each date with next ones
    c = d
    while c in dic:                    # get consecutive dates starting from d
        if c>d: dic[d] += dic.pop(c)   # merge/remove later date
        c += timedelta(days=1)         # check further 
        
print(dic)
# {datetime.date(2021, 1, 2): 2, datetime.date(2021, 1, 5): 1}
```

This will work even when the dates are not in ascending order so you don't need to sort and will get O(n) time complexity

*Note that this solution does not take into account the possibility of duplicate dates in the list (i.e. each date only counts for 1 even if there are multiple instances in the list)*

Comment: You have a while on the dictionary keys inside the for. Saying it is O(n) is a little bit optimistic (depending on how the dict is sorted you may need to check most of the remaining keys at every iteration).

Comment: Perhaps it is, but my reasoning is that, since each element in `dic` is removed as it is processed, the total number iterations in that while can never be more than 2N.  This should come up to a total of 3N at worst. So I estimated that T(3N) = O(N).

Comment: That depends on the data. If all items represent non-consecutive days nothing is removed from the dictionary and you may end up with something that approaches O(n^2): so you're in between O(n) and O(n^2) depending on the dict implementation and the values you're working with. Note that I am not saying your algorithm is bad, in fact I like this approach that does not depend on the initial data to be sorted and that works directly on the result itself. :)

Comment: Nope, if there are no consecutive days, the while loop will do exactly two iterations per date.  Or more precisely, one finds the date, the second doesn't.

Comment: Every time the while loop does find a consecutive date (i.e. +1 iteration), removal of the date from dic will bring down the iterations for that other date to exactly 1 because it won't be found on the very first iteration.  So each date/next-date is found exactly once and not-found exactly once.   Python dictionary access is O(1) by design

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the intrinsic complexity of the "in" operation. Depending on the implementation (hash, tree, key/value list) it can go from O(1) to O(n). If you never remove anything and have a large dictionary the "in" operation can be quite expensive.

Comment: To be honest, there IS a worst case scenario where the total cumulative time of the while loops would be 3N (but still linear overall).  That is if the dates are sorted in decreasing order.  This will take two iterations for the first date and 3 iterations per date for the rest.

Comment: This already got too long (my fault!) Thank you for the discussion. :)